# nested dictionary sorting

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, dictionary

I've been trying to figure out how to sort these dictionaries: `d1` and `d2`inside the dictionary `d3`.

```
d1 = {'eggs':1, 'cheese':1}
d2 = {'cake':1, 'cream':1}
d3 = {'breakfast':{},'dessert':{}}
d3['breakfast'] = d1
d3['dessert'] = d2
for k,v in sorted(d3.items()):
    for k,v in sorted(d3['breakfast'].items()):
        for k,v in sorted(d3.items()):
            print(k,v)
```

This is the output:

```
breakfast {'eggs': 1, 'cheese': 1}
dessert {'cream': 1, 'cake': 1}
breakfast {'eggs': 1, 'cheese': 1}
dessert {'cream': 1, 'cake': 1}
breakfast {'eggs': 1, 'cheese': 1}
dessert {'cream': 1, 'cake': 1}
breakfast {'eggs': 1, 'cheese': 1}
dessert {'cream': 1, 'cake': 1}
```

It sorts the two `breakfast` and `dessert` correctly, then inside `dessert`, `'cream'` and `'eggs'` are in the wrong order.

It should be:

```
dessert {'cake':1, 'cream':1}
```

and it also prints the "sorted" dictionary `d3` four times, and I'm not exactly sure why.

For all I know, there could be a more effective way to be doing this, so any information is welcome.

Comment: Please explain what you *wanted* to happen (e.g. what output you wanted to see), as it is not clear from your question.

Comment: this is unlogical code, because you could do just the last for loop, you'd get two outputs, i don't get your code

Comment: You should not have 3 nested `for` loops that all have the same loop variables (`k` and `v`) since the two outer loops are basically just making the inner one run 4x.  Notice that just doing `print(k,v)` is printing out `v` being the whole dictionary unsorted.

Comment: still trying to get the hang loops, i didn't really have an intended format i just wanted them sorted and printed. i kinda figured i had one to many loops but every variation i tried didn't work. i mean i didnt even understand what the k and v stood for less than an hour ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your algorithm has a few problems, mostly that you're nesting way too many times and looping over the same thing each time. Here's a better algorithm:

```
for k,v in sorted(d3.items()):
    print(k + ":")
    for k2,v2 in sorted(v.items()):
        print("\t" + k2 + ", " + str(v2))
```

It formats the answer like this:

```
breakfast:
    cheese, 1
    eggs, 1
dessert:
    cake, 1
    cream, 1
```

I wasn't sure what your intended format is - hopefully you can modify it to be what you'd like. As you can see, this time the loop iterates first over d3, **then over the elements of d3**, rather than d3 again. This means that you'll go another level deep in the nested dictionary, rather than what you were doing before which was printing the same dictionary multiple times.

Comment: so i tried that and i had to add () to the print statments because it gave me an error, at first it wasnt working but then i just had the () around the wrong thing. its working now thanks! this was just a test code to get the idea of how it works then implement it into another program im working on.

Comment: Did it not work for you? Were you intending to do something different? I'm going to need more information than that

Comment: sorry i keep pressing enter and it posts the comment when i mean to go down a line. im going to try and implement this into my main program, if i need some more help can i just add it to this question?

Answer (score 0):

```
d1 = {'eggs':1, 'cheese':1}
d2 = {'cake':1, 'cream':1}
d3 = {'breakfast':{},'dessert':{}}
d3['breakfast'] = d1
d3['dessert'] = d2
for key,val in sorted(d3.items()):
    print(key,val)
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".